# Using PHP to upload to Amazon S3

Tags: php, upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've spent the last few hours following tutorials for implementing file uploads to Amazon S3 using php.  I uploaded the most recent version of Donovan Schönknecht's S3 class to my server (as S3.php) and I am trying to use the following code to test upload capability.  I know this code will work because I've seen numerous examples in action.

```
<?php

require('S3.php');

$s3 = new S3('KEY', 'SECRET KEY');

//insert into s3
$new_name = time() . '.txt';

S3::putObject(
'upload-me.txt',
'bucketName',
$new_name,
S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
array(),
array(),
S3::STORAGE_CLASS_RRS

);

?>
```

I get an error 500 server error when I attempt to load this page.  Additionally, every other reputable tutorial of this nature has given me the same error 500.

I verified that my key and secret key are valid by connecting to S3 with Cyberduck.

Does anyone have a clue as to what I could be doing incorrectly?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: 500 error is probably an error in your php code. Turn on display_errors or check your logs to see the error message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it turns out, I was missing the cURL extension for PHP and this was causing an issue as the  S3 class I was using required the use of cURL.  All is working now.

Answer (score 9):

You should also consider using the official [AWS SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php). Examples for using S3 with the SDK can be found in their [S3 user guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/service-s3.html).

Comment: The official AWS SDK for PHP only works with composer and there is no ZIP file download anymore. I can not use composer on a shared hosting platform for some of my websites.

Comment: There is a zip and phar included in [every release](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases) that includes the entire closure dependencies such that Composer is not required.

Comment: The SDK's README and user guide both [show where to download the zip](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html). Is there some particular reason you though that the SDK only worked with Composer?

Comment: That is great news! I was under the impression that after Ver 1.6, Ver 2.0 would require composer. I'll try later the week

Answer (score 8):

You can download most recent version of Amazon PHP SDK by running following composer command

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

Further configuration to upload file on Amazon s3 are following

```
// Include the SDK using the Composer autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

// Set Amazon s3 credentials
$client = S3Client::factory(
  array(
    'key'    => "your-key",
    'secret' => "your secret key"
  )
);

try {
  $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'=>'your-bucket-name',
    'Key' =>  'your-filepath-in-bucket',
    'SourceFile' => 'source-filename-with-path',
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
  ));

} catch (S3Exception $e) {
  // Catch an S3 specific exception.
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Get step by step  details from here [Amazon S3 File Upload Using PHP](http://phpclicks.com/amazon-s3-file-upload-using-php/)

Answer (score 3):

Following example worked for me:

```
<?php
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$client = S3Client::factory([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-west-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => "<scret-key>",
        'secret' => "<my-secret>"
    ]
 ]);

try {
    $client->putObject([
        'Bucket'     =>'<my-bucket-name>',
        'Key'        => '<file-name>',
        'SourceFile' => '<file-path-on-server>',    // like /var/www/vhosts/mysite/file.csv
        'ACL'        => 'public-read',
    ]);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    // Catch an S3 specific exception.
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Getting security credentials:**

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/wheres-my-secret-access-key/
- https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/security_credential

**Getting region code**

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Answer (score 1):

Use this one to Upload Images using a form and it's working Fine for me 
you may try using it with your code

```
$name = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['photo']['size'];
$tmp = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];

//////Upload Process


    // Bucket Name
    $bucket = 'bucket-name';
    require_once('S3.php');

    //AWS access info
    $awsAccessKey = 'awsAccessKey';
    $awsSecretKey = 'awsSecretKey';

    //instantiate the class
    $s3 = new S3($awsAccessKey, $awsSecretKey);

    $s3->putBucket($bucket, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);


    //Rename image name. 
    $actual_image_name = time();

        //Upload to S3
    if($s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $actual_image_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) )
    {
        $image='http://'.$bucket.'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$actual_image_name;
    }else{
        echo 'error uploading to S3 Amazon';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I never found a updated Script with Amazons latest sdk. i have made it by myself. it woks as a php commandline interpreter script. give it a try :

https://github.com/arizawan/aiss3clientphp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with S3 API, but i used it as the storage with https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette. Gaufrette is a library that provides pretty nice abstraction layer above S3 and other file services/systems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code to upload images on Amazon S3.

```
// Bucket Name
$bucket="BucketName";
if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');

    //AWS access info
    if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'ACCESS_KEY');
    if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'ACCESS_Secret_KEY');

    $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    $s3->putBucket($bucket, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
    if($s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $image_name_actual,S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) )
    {
        $message = "S3 Upload Successful.";
        $s3file='http://'.$bucket.'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$actual_image_name;
        echo "<img src='$s3file'/>";
        echo 'S3 File URL:'.$s3file;
    }
    else{
        $message = "S3 Upload Fail.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the best solution. Its using multipart upload.Make Sure to install Aws SDK for PHP before using**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use Aws\S3\MultipartUploader;
use Aws\Exception\MultipartUploadException;

try {
  $s3Client = new S3Client([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'AKIAUMIZJR5U5IO7M3',
        'secret' => 'BmcA3vFso1bc/9GVK7nHJtFk0tQL6Vi5OoMySO',
    ],
  ]);
 
  // Use multipart upload
  $source = 'https://b8q9h6y2.stackpathcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/banner-for-website-4.png';
  $uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3Client, $source, [
      'bucket' => 'videofilessandeep',
      'key' => 'my-file.png',
      'ACL' => 'public-read',
  ]);
  
  try {
      $result = $uploader->upload();
      echo "Upload complete: {$result['ObjectURL']}\n";
  } catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
  }
 } catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Comment: are those your real credentials? better not to share them publicly!